# Web to SSRS via ReportViewer - how to make the connection faster?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have some webforms in my MVC application that contain report viewers that display some SSRS reports.
Particulary when I invoke a report this way the first time, the connection is very slow.
How do I improve the performance of this?
My report viewer on my webform looks like this;

```
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"
        Height="1205px" Width="1000px">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="/Report_SHP_EmployeeHistory/ReportAllLeave" 
            DisplayName="Report Annual Leave" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the report would run faster outside the ReportViewer control?  And that the underlying queries are faster?

Comment: Yes because it is only the first time when I access the report. Subsequent retrievals are much faster, and to be honest we are only talking about a small database and a simple here.

Answer (score 0):

I Think its the limitation with the Report Service. The first report you are viewing after the service restart will take time to view the report. This happen for me also. I am using the report server directly to view the report.

Comment: So you are not using Report Viewer. As I understand it there is no other way a MVC application can link to SSRS.